# Upload image in django and decoder jpeg not available

Tags: python, django, image, upload, image-uploading

I'm trying upload image in my old django (1.0.4) project. It was working before but now I'm receiving error 500.

Below is part of traceback:

```
IOError at /gallery
decoder jpeg not available
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://myproject.com/gallery
Exception Type: IOError
Exception Value:    
decoder jpeg not available
```

I have installed (to working with images):

- PIL==1.1.7
- Pillow==2.6.1

I did also upgrade - pillow and pil:

```
pip install Pillow==2.6.1 --upgrade
Requirement already up-to-date: Pillow==2.6.1 in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Cleaning up...
```

and

```
pip install PIL==1.1.7 --upgrade
Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement PIL==1.1.7 in ./venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL
Downloading/unpacking PIL==1.1.7
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for PIL==1.1.7 in ./venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL
```